# How to create vectors in a loop

Tags: r, loops, vector

In R, when I write

```
i=10
y=c(i:i+9)
y
```

I get 19 in output, whereas when I directly write

```
y = c(10:19)
y
```

Why does this happen? What does the expression mean when written in terms of i? How to do that in a loop (because I have value stored in counter variable in that case)?

Comment: parenthesis y=c(i:(i+9))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checkout:

```
?Syntax
```

`:` has higher precedence  than `+`. It's an order of operations issue like arithmetic.

First:

```
10:10
```

Evaluates to `10`. Then:

```
10 + 9
```

Evaluates to `19`